# Divide an array into bins

Tags: python, arrays, bin

I have a file.dat with three columns (x,y and z) like this:

```
  2.89e+13 1.56 5.78 
  4.76e+12 7.12 2.35
  2.01e+10 4.53 7.23
  ........ .... ....
```

I would like to divide the x array into three bins and evaluate the median of each, then plot y as a function of x (so, essentially it should give me 3 points, one for each bin). Do you know if I have to divide in bins the y array too? I have also to plot(x,y) for values of z greater than a certain value. So I divided the z array into two bins in this way:

```
index_above = (z > 6)
z = z[index_above] 
index_below = (z < 6)
z = z[index_below]
```

This is what I have done for x:

```
idx1 = ((x >= 10**(10)) & (x < 10**(11)))
x1 = x[idx1]
median_x1 = np.median(x1)
......
```

and for y:

```
y1 = y[idx1]
median_y1 = np.median(y1)
....
```

for the 3 bins. How can I plot now y as a function of x for values of z>6 and z<6 and put the two plots in the same one?

Comment: How are you defining the contents of the bins? Should the bins be of similar size?

Comment: If you're only plotting 3 points in y vs.  then yes, you need to group the `y` points as well.

Comment: What kind of data structure are you using? Probably you'll want to group your corresponding x, y and z values before splitting them up into bins. If you were using basic Python lists (or iterables) I'd suggest `zip` but other data types may have better alternatives.